# JavaScript request object- convert key as a variable to string

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm a programming beginner.

API post call accepts object variable (derived from variable) as a string as follows

```
"option": 
    {           
  "235": “30”
},
 {           
    "238": “32”
}
```

My code angular 6

```
  option = [];
  ---

    this.option.push({
      [option.product_option_id]: $event
    });
```

which result

```
 option = [ {
   235: 30
 }]
```

but need this variable in double-quoted "235".

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but need this variable in double-quoted "235"

By which you mean that you need it to be a *string*.

Don't worry, it is. When you use a number as a property name, it's converted to a string automatically. Property names can only be strings or Symbols, so things that aren't strings or Symbols get converted to string:

```js
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.option = [];
        const option = {
          product_option_id: 42
        };
        const $event = {};

        this.option.push({
          [option.product_option_id]: $event
        });

        const pushed = this.option[0];
        for (const key of Object.keys(pushed)) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${typeof key}`);
        }
    }
}
new Example();
```

That said, the expression within the `[]` of a computed property name is just that: an expression. So if you wanted to be explicit, you could use `String` there:

```
option.push({
  [String(option.product_option_id)]: $event
});
```